# SharePoint 2016: Users forced to re-authenticate unexpectedly

Tags: authentication

Users are being forced to reauthenticate. We have tried setting a few configurations via PowerShell that we read about online, but nothing seems to change this problem.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. If anyone has their settings so that people stay logged on for 8  hours or even longer, it wold be great to see what you have set.

Here is a script that we ran:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
$mysts = Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig
#$mysts.WindowsTokenLifetime = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 20)
#$mysts.LogonTokenCacheExpirationWindow = (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 19)
#$mysts.Update()

#Set-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig -ServiceTokenLifetime 1000
```

Comment: How exactly are they forced to re-authenticate? Does it happen during site browsing or when they make a first request after some time of inactivity?

Comment: I will  check on when this happens -